# Why does python demand that docstrings be indented?

Tags: python

Why does python accept this code:

```
def is_right_triangle(leg1,leg2,hypotenuse):
    """function for checking whether or not set of points makes a right triangle"""
    return leg1 ** 2 + leg2 ** 2  == hypotenuse ** 2
```

but in this code, where the docstring is not indented

```
def is_right_triangle(leg1,leg2,hypotenuse):
 """function for checking whether or not set of points makes a right triangle"""
    return leg1 ** 2 + leg2 ** 2  == hypotenuse ** 2
```

it throws an "expected an indented block" error.

Why does python care if the docstring is indented or not?

Comment: Because a docstring is an actual string and indentation matters in Python.

Comment: So in other words, python considers the docstring to be part of the function.

Comment: It's just a string. Of course, it is associated with the function, but the point is it needs to be parsed according to Python's syntax rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the docstring is just another expression in the function. It's only treated in a special way because it's the a string and the first expression.

You can also see that by getting the function ast:

```
> a=ast.parse('def f(x):\n    "docstring"\n    return 0')
> a.body[0].body
[<_ast.Expr at 0x7f18bb3e6a20>, <_ast.Return at 0x7f18bb3e6550>]
> a.body[0].body[0].value.s
'docstring'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because at the very beginning of python in the 1990's, Guido Van Rossum decreed that all statements in a function definition should be indented and that a string was an expression statement.

Only GvR can really answer this question. Python comes from a toy language named [ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_(programming_language)). The docstring may already have been indented in ABC...

Comment: A string *is* an expression statement. If you don't like it, you are free to stick # in front of it and turn it into a comment. Of course it is then not a formal docstring. There are other languages and/or documentation systems that treat certain comments as special, for example #pragma. I prefer Python's way.

Comment: @nigel222 I'm not saying I don't like it, I'm only saying I don't know all the arguments in GvR's head when he decided that docstrings should have this syntax. There may have been some comment habit from ABC.

Comment: @Griboulis Sorry that came over too personal. My point is that the syntax on the language means that a docstring is an expression statement by definition, just as a string on a line by itself is an expression statement anywhere else in the code. And as a statement rather than a comment, it must be appropriately indented.

Comment: @nigel222 I understand your point in the sense that it is coherent with the rest of python's grammar. But you're missing the fact that in the end, it is completely arbitrary.